# JAVA: Graph creation

Tags: java, graph, nodes, edges

I'm new to object oriented programming and I'm stuck on this: [image: todo]

So far I've made the first 2 points but I'm not sure if the second is right, here's the code:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Node {
    private String name;
    private Rectangle rectangle;


    public Node(int x, int y, int width, int height, String name) {
        this.rectangle =new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Node() {
        this.rectangle = new Rectangle (0,0,0,0); //gonna change the parameters later
        this.name = "default name";
    }

}
```

My first question is: How am I supposed to make a class that represents an edge? It is kind of abstract for me. Should  just make a class with 2 members being nodes and a basic constructor? Something like:

```
public class Edge {
    private Node nodeA;
    private Node nodeB;

    public Edge(Node nodeA, Node nodeB) {
        this.nodeA = nodeA;
        this.nodeB = nodeB;
    }
```

And my second question is: How should I keep track of the nodes and edges for the 4th point? I've read something about Adjacency Lists but I'm not entirely sure. Also, I've seen that there are libraries made for that but I'm not sure if I am allowed to do that.

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Read through these chapters. [4.1](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/41graph/) [4.2](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/42digraph/) They are not long. If you have the book, then that's even better. The explanations with diagrams are really helpful and easy to understand. This is what an adjacency list looks like: https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/41graph/images/adjacency-lists.png It's basically a list of lists (for your case at least). You can represent this in any other way (like a hashmap of of lists).

Comment: If you check out that diagram, you'll see that 0 node is connected to 6, 2, 1 and 5. And if you will see that 6, 2, 1 and 5 have a 0 in their list. You'll basically have to create this class https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/41graph/images/graph-api.png

Comment: @Radu You can implement an `adjacency matrix` as a 2D array of `Node[][]` and have it in your `GraphModel` implementation. Alternately, if your graph is relatively sparse, consider implementing an `adjacency list` using a `List<Node>[]`.